# underset and mathbf don't work when package breqn is imported

Tags: bold, breqn

Here is a Minimal Reproducible Example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

% Packages

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{breqn}



\begin{document}    
    \begin{equation}
         \pmb{\beta_i}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        \underset{\mathbf{x}}{\text{argmin}}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

What I want:
[image]

What I have:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Never use `\pmb`, but `\bm`.

Also `\underset` is not the right tool for the job and `breqn` has nothing to do.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Packages

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{breqn}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}

\begin{document}    

\begin{equation}
  \bm{\beta}_{i}+\argmin_{\mathbf{x}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "breqn has nothing to do"?

Comment: Also, why "Never use \pmb, but \bm."?

Comment: Also, thank you for the argmin tip, it makes more sense like this!